# Remove Hashtag from url

Tags: uri

In a Drupal site, I've a hashtag appended to my url. Example:

```
www.myUrl.com/content/node#.UFnCybLN9Nu
```

I don't know where it comes from and I don't know how to remove it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is coming from the [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) service (media sharing icons). You maybe copied a link from there or if you are using that module, you selected to track the shared links.

If it's your widget, you can disable it by removing a line in JS (there is something like `"track = true"` in the widget code).

Comment: That was the culprit. I've learn something :)