# Code in URLs despite clean URLs turned on

Tags: uri

The site I'm working on, shows the URL like this: `http://www.sitename.com/page-name#.Uad4adKmjoY`

It shows "`#.Uad4adKmjoY`" at the end of url, even though I've enabled the clean urls.

Anyone know why it is showing this? I've not come across this before.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589256/a-random-xxxxxxxxxxx-string-is-added-to-my-url-when-i-use-the-addthis-code) on StackOwerflow and this one on [Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/44170/remove-hashtag-from-url), these appear if there is Javascript in place to add "[AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/)" tracking to the website.  They do no harm, and if it's not your site, you should leave them alone.

(Note that this has nothing to do with clean URLs in Drupal.  Drupal's clean URLs changes things like `example.com/?q=node/123` into  `example.com/node/123`.  It does nothing with hashmarks added to URLs.)